# IoS / Swift - How to display images from the iphone 's albums into a uicollection view?

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to display all the photos from the phone's album/gallery into a view controller by making use of the UICollectionView.

I simply do not know how to retrieve all the images from the albums and automatically displaying them.  UIImagePicker allows the user to choose the image but in my case I would like the app to retrieve the photos - without user intervention - and then display them on a collection view.

Can you please hint me on how to get this done?

Comment: Do research on the Photos framework.

Comment: good question. People starting iOS dev from scratch may not know about the Photos framework!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this code it might help you

```
let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
fetchOptions.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "localIdentifier = %@", YourAlbumLocalIdentifier)
let resultCollections = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollectionsWithType(.Album, subtype: .AlbumRegular, options: fetchOptions)
```